# Howto: Model scope for todays records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey,
how do I set a scope in rails 3 to todays records?

This doent work, yet. I get no data.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :today, :conditions => { :created_at => Date.today }
end
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since "created_at" column contains date and time, but you need compare only date, you have two ways (I assume you use MySQL) :

1. use **BETWEEN**:
   `scope :today, lambda { WHERE("created_at BETWEEN '#{DateTime.now.beginning_of_day}' AND '#{DateTime.now.end_of_day}'")  }`
2. use **DATE()** function:
   `scope :today, lambda { WHERE('DATE(created_at) = ?', Date.today)}`

also, you can add "created_on" column to the table with date only.

**Updated:**

```
def self.up
   add_column table_name, :created_on, :date  
   add_column table_name, :updated_on, :date
end
```

`scope :today, lambda { where(created_on: Date.today) }`

Comment: How do I tell rails (rake) to create a date only field?

Comment: You just need to add "created_on" and "update_on" field to the table.
These column names are special, so values will be set automatically by Rails.

Comment: Final scope: 
  scope :today, lambda {
    where("created_on = ?", Date.today)
  }

Answer (score 16):

I think you can define a general scope like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :created_on, lambda {|date| {:conditions => ['created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day]}}

  def self.today
    self.created_on(Date.today)
  end
end
```

So you can use

```
>> MyModel.today #-> records created today
>> MyModel.created_on(Date.today - 1.week) #-> records created a week ago
```

Comment: Technically, should probably be `created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?`, otherwise you'll have two whole seconds missing! Also, in `self.today`, you need `self.created_**on**`, rather than `created_**at**`.

Comment: I fixed '>' and '<' for '>=' and '<=' - we don't want to miss any second ;) And of course there should be created_on not created_at - thanks for the comment and corrections!

Answer (score 8):

Rails evaluates the scope at the class level so when you use :conditions => { :created_at => Date.today } it evaluates Date.today and compare all records with pre evaluated date. To avoid this use lamda to define date or time specific scopes

```
 scope :today, lambda { :conditions =>[ "created_at = ? ", Date.today] }
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'
...today, lambda { :conditions => { :created_at => Date.today }...

Comment: Got the point:  "created_at" column contains date and time, but i need to need compare only date (day, without time)

Answer (score 3):

I know that is a old question, but still can help anyone.

This was my way to solve this:

`scope :today, -> { where(created_at: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..DateTime.now.end_of_day) }`

Comment: looking through the docs and back at this, I found this to be more flexible and helpful for me `scope :date, ->(date) { where(created_at: date.to_time.beginning_of_day..date.to_time.end_of_day) }`

Answer (score 2):

IMO this is the most understandable way to do it.

```
  def self.created_today
    where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", Date.today, Date.tomorrow)
  end
```