# Rails: Limiting the index view to show today's entries only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running Ruby 2 and Rails 4.

I am creating an app where you can track the calories and macronutrients of each meal, but I want the Meal Index to only show what each user enters for today, not every meal they've ever entered.

I currently have it showing only what is entered on each day, but the total at the bottom is all meals that have ever been entered, not just today's total. I can't add the `.created_at.to_date == Date.current` on to the `@meals` variable. It throws an `undefined method 'created_at' for 1500:Fixnum`

Each user has a BMR which then calculates how many calories etc they have remaining for the particular day.

**My Index view on my MealsController:**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Calories</th>
      <th>Protein</th>
      <th>Carbs</th>
      <th>Fats</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @meals.each do |meal| %>
      <tr class= "value">
        <% if meal.created_at.to_date == Date.current %>
          <td><%= link_to meal.name, edit_meal_path(meal) %></td>
          <td><%= meal.calories %></td>
          <td><%= meal.protein %></td>
          <td><%= meal.carbohydrates %></td>
          <td><%= meal.fats %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
      <tr>
        <td class="meal-total">Total:</td>
        <td class="meal-total"><%= @meals.sum(:calories) %></td>
        <td class="meal-total"><%= @meals.sum(:protein) %></td>
        <td class="meal-total"><%= @meals.sum(:carbohydrates) %></td>
        <td class="meal-total"><%= @meals.sum(:fats) %></td>
      </tr>
      <% unless current_user.bmr.nil? %>
        <tr class="remaining">
          <td class="meal-remaining">Remaining:</td>
          <td class="meal-remaining"><%= current_user.bmr - @meals.sum(:calories) %></td>
          <td class="meal-remaining"><%= (current_user.bmr*0.4/4).to_i - @meals.sum(:protein) %></td>
          <td class="meal-remaining"><%= (current_user.bmr*0.4/4).to_i - @meals.sum(:carbohydrates) %></td>
          <td class="meal-remaining"><%= (current_user.bmr*0.2/9).to_i - @meals.sum(:fats) %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**My MealsController:**

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_meal, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :index

  def index
    @meals = current_user.meals if user_signed_in?
  end
  .
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would take the logic for this out of the view and put it into the controllers.

You could then define two instance variables.

```
@todays_meals = current_user.meals.where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day)
@previous_meals = current_user.meals.where("created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day)
```

When you do this you're relying on the database the do the sorting rather than rails or ruby and that results in a faster operation. Also, keeping logic out of the view is a big win as well.

Edit:

As Davidann mentioned within the comment, you could also accomplish this by creating a scope within the model. Below is an implementation of that.

meal.rb

```
scope :today, lambda {
  where('created_at > ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day)
  .where('created_at < ?', Time.now.end_of_day) 
}

@user.meals.today
```

If you find yourself doing my first implementation many times, create a scope like the one above. If not, then it is up to you whether or not you would like this scope to be within your model or within your controller. Also, note that the **lamdba** within the scope is required to allow the Time.now to be called each time the scope call is evaluated.

Comment: FWIW, it might be better practice to have "thin controllers" and "fat models."  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550376/rails-skinny-controller-vs-fat-model-or-should-i-make-my-controller-anorexic) for more details.

Comment: I've tried restarting my server, but it's still giving me this: /Users/lukemacauley/tracktrack/app/controllers/meals_controller.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')' ...als.where("created_at < ?" Time.now.beginning_of_day) ... ^ /Users/lukemacauley/tracktrack/app/controllers/meals_controller.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end /Users/lukemacauley/tracktrack/app/controllers/meals_controller.rb:61: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Comment: Just worked it out: you missed a comma after `"created_at < ?"`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways of doing it, the easiest being adding [an ActiveRecord scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) that only dishes out todays meals.

[This SO question/answers has several methods of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947214/howto-model-scope-for-todays-records), pick your favorite.

After that, you'd just change this:

```
def index
  @meals = current_user.meals.today if user_signed_in?
end
```

Comment: You've added the same link twice. Can you expand a little on the best way to scope it to today's meals?

Comment: Sorry about that, updated it...  Googling "rails scope today" gets you there, it's a pretty common thing.  Hope you got it working!